# How to change font style and background color in titleForHeaderInSection method

Tags: ios, uitableview

after long reading and checking code, I am proud to have a custom table view with sections and section titles, all populated from core data objects. Now I would need to customize the section title and background color. I have seen it done but in a `viewForHeaderInSection` method. Is is not possible inside my `titleForHeaderInSection` method?
Here you have my method:

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{




    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
    NSString *sectionname = [theSection name];
    if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"text 1"]){
        return @"Today";

    }
    else if ([sectionname isEqualToString:@"text 2"]){
        return @"Tomorrow";
    }


    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController sections]count]>0){
        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
        return [sectionInfo name];
    }
    else{
        return nil;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example that uses your existing code to set the title text, but lets you use UITableViewHeaderFooterView to adjust the appearance:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *header = @"customHeader";

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

    vHeader = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];

    if (!vHeader) {
        vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
        vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    vHeader.textLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    return vHeader;
}
```

If you want, you can even subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` just like you'd subclass `UITableViewCell` to customize the appearance even further.

Comment: that works, thank you, could I select a different background color on each section title?

Comment: Sure! Anything that changes should be outside the scope of the if (!vHeader) conditional.  Anything that's always the same should be inside it. (Just like with table cells.)

Comment: Thank you, I have changed background color depending on the section value, and works, but now I would need to add the number of rows in the section as label beside the title, like TODAY (6), TOMORROW (17)..could I implement this also inside this method?

Comment: This is depreciated as you iOS 9.

Comment: @AnkishJain `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:` doesn't appear deprecated in the docs. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 26):

simple and optimized

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//[UIColor colorWithRed:77.0/255.0 green:162.0/255.0 blue:217.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    // Text Color
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [header.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableSection"]]];

}
```

Comment: Clever, but worth noting this might crash in future versions of iOS since the API does not guarantee that `view` is a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. Might want to use conditional casting to be safer.

Answer (score 11):

Swift implementation of @codercat's answer:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    view.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.967, green: 0.985, blue: 0.998, alpha: 1) // this example is a light blue, but of course it also works with UIColor.lightGray

    var header : UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel.textColor = .red

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) be a better solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Make a Custom HeaderView by :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *viewHeader = [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 28)];
    UILabel *lblTitle =[UILabel.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6, 3, 136, 21)]; 
    [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13]]; //Font style 
    [lblTitle setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; 
    [lblTitle setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft]; 
    [lblTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; //Background
    [viewHeader addSubview:lblTitle];
    return viewHeader;
}
```

Give this label any text; I suggest make a seperate NSArray for header titles.

Comment: thank you, but I need titleForHeaderInSection method to keep the current method to create the section rows and titles...

Comment: why specifically , it can solve your problem the viewForHeaderInSection Method :

id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> theSection = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections]objectAtIndex:section];
get any value and set Label Text via this Fetched results Array.

Comment: you mean I could use the same code lines from titleForHeaderInSection in a viewForHeaderInSection method, and then add your proposal to format text and background colour?

Comment: Exactly only use to get fetched results from NSFetchResultsSection.... 

And set Label title from it. Simples.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in `titleForHeaderInSection` you can't change section view properties. 
Add to your project  `viewForHeaderInSection` and then add custom custom view with label on it, e.g.
see this hint:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 0)] autorelease];

    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,300, TABLE_HEADER_HEIGHT);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = TABLE_HEADER_TITLE_COLOR;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:14.f];

    label.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    if (section == 3) {
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    } else {
        [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    [headerView addSubview:label];

    return headerView;
}
```

You can set title for label according section number.

Comment: You shouldn't use UIView here, it's not reusable.

Comment: In my opinion everything with my code is good, UIView there shouldn't be reusable.

Comment: what kind of errors? You shouldn't copy one to one that code, this is hint for your customization, e.g. TABLE_HEADER_HEIGHT and TABLE_HEADER_TITLE_COLOR are defined by me values.